# EventHandler with a different type of sender

Tags: c#, object, events, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to implement drag and drop for a specific object of a Type that I've created in c# for windows phone 8. I'm using Manipulation Events like this :

```
deck[r[i, j]].card.ManipulationCompleted += new EventHandler<ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>(ImageManipulationCompleted);

private void ImageManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //something
}
```

How can I change object to the type that I want ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to cast `sender` as the `card` type? Or do you want `sender` to be any object that you choose?

Comment: I want sender to be the deck[r[i,j]] type. Card is an image, but deck[r[i,j]]  contains two more integers that I need to use in the eventhandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keyboardP's solution will work just fine. But I personally prefer to store the information I need in the `Tag` property of the control, which has been designed for this very purpose.

```
deck[r[i, j]].card.Tag = deck[r[i, j]];
deck[r[i, j]].card.ManipulationCompleted += ImageManipulationCompleted;

private void ImageManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var deck = (Deck)((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag;
}
```

The good side of keyboardP's approach is that, since you receive directly the desired object as a parameter of your method, it's easier to read. The downside is that you have to declare a custom delegate for every event you need, and you lose the ability to assign event handlers directly from the XAML. My solution is a bit harder to read, but addresses this point.

In the end, which solution is better really depends on your tastes and your needs.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is just call a method that takes in your `type` instead of using the standard `ImageManipulationCompleted` handler. I don't know what the `deck[r[i, j]]` type is but you can replace `MyType` below with the correct type.

```
deck[r[i, j]].card.ManipulationCompleted += delegate(object s, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e){ CardManipulated(s, e, deck[r[i, j]]); };

private void CardManipulated(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e, MyType selectedObject)
{
    //you know have access to selectedObject which is of type deck[r[i, j]],
    //the ManipluationCompletedEvents properties if needed,
    //and the actual card Image object (sender).
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant.

Since you are subscribing to an event with this code `new EventHandler<>(..)`, you cannot change the type of `sender` because in the description of `EventHandler<>` there is only `object` sender:

```
public delegate EventHandler<T>(object sender, T eventArgs) where T : EventArgs
```

If you need to create your own delegate, you could make a factory or simply write this:

```
public delegate EventHandler<T, TArgs>(T sender, TArgs eventArgs) where TTArgs : EventArgs
```

Answer (score 0):

`ManipulationCompletedEventHandler` signature is using object in its first parameter

```
public delegate void ManipulationCompletedEventHandler(object sender, 
                         ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e);
```

So, you can't change the signature but you can `use delegate to typecast` object always to `your type` like this -

```
deck[r[i, j]].card.ManipulationCompleted += (s, e) => 
           ManipulateMe_ManipulationCompleted((YourType)s, e);

private void ImageManipulationCompleted(YourType sender,
                               ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //something
}
```

Replace `YourType` with your desired `Type` (TextBox or something whichever you want)

Comment: I receive InvalidCastException

Comment: @user2623966 - You can't cast the `sender` to just any type. It's going to be of type `Image` because your `card` property stores an image and it's that that's firing the `ManipulationCompleted` event.

Comment: As keyboardP mentioned you should cast it to actual sender and not any random type. This will even fail when you try to cast in previous handler as well.